# front struts 2000 taurus can not knock out lower mounting bolt. nut is off

Tags: struts

I CAN NOT KNOCK THE BOLT itsself out from the lower end of strut mount. i got the nut off butt am unable to hammer the bolt out. front strut passenger side 2000 taurus

Comment: Pictures would probably help, have you tried supporting the mount with a jack at various levels to see if that releases some of the shearing force?

Comment: Will the bolt turn?

Comment: is this the style where the spindle clamps around the lower portion of the strut? I'd use some heat and a air hammer or an impact gun to either hammer the bolt out or spin it.

Answer (score 5):

I had a Jeep Wrangler like that once.  Heap'o'rust.  Get yourself one of these.  Works awesome.

[image: Pneumatic Air Hammer]

I hammered on bolts for a few hours on that fricking jeep.  With this, it took just minutes.  And of course the safety warning.  You will need ear and eye protection.  Stay safe out there...